# Various site icon problems

Tags: bug, design

This has been bothering me for a long time.

Roughly sorted by perceived sizes, you can see how the first and last icons are very different:

[image]

On the [Hot Questions page](https://stackexchange.com/), they look [rather different in size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1R5n.png).

Some icons aren't using complementing colors for backgrounds and end up being less visible:

[image]

Also I noticed that many 48px and 32px icons have different look, fonts and colors, and some beta-style have blurry text/symbols:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

It's a small thing but I think it could be improved.

Comment: Why *should* they be visually consistent?

Comment: Why *shouldn't* they? I think it would be much neater. For one thing, it would bother me less, and probably a number of others who didn't quite feel like it's worth posting a meta about it, but still felt annoyed.

Comment: I strongly disagree. The whole point of independent designs is that they are independent, there is no reason for them to be consistent at all. It's a matter of opinion so that fine but I can't see any *design* reason for it (and it's certainly not a bug).

Comment: [Look here.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/63hYf.png) Do you strongly disagree that these icons should be sized similarly? I don't think it's a good idea to make icons differently sized in lists, which HNQ sidebar and main page are. And to my knowledge these icons of that specific size don't appear anywhere else where the size difference would be noticeable, so it's not like resizing them would ruin the whole look of the site. The bug portion refers to the parts at the end of the post.

Comment: Hmm, looking again there is a noticeable difference on the HNQ *page*. The icons are actually sized differently there so I see your point. But if you look at the [favicon spritesheet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/img/favicons-sprite32.png) that is used for the HNQ *sidebar*, you can see the icons do fill the space available to them, the problem is that not all the icons fit nicely in a square. The only solution there is to reduce the size of all the icons to accommodate the visually lightest, which isn't ideal and would need to be recalculated every time there is a new site deisgn

Comment: Nice find, these 32px ones look neat. The HNQ page uses 48px icons though, and they're not looking great.